# Unable to add new documents to a collection in Firestore using Functions:Shell

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to add a document to a subcollection in Firestore using the Firebase shell:

`firebase functions:shell`

Running that gives us a shell we can run queries and code in. It seems that I can't `add` documents to a collection for some odd reason.

Here's the script I'm running in the shell:

```
  await db.collection('balances')
    .doc(docId)
    .collection('history')
    .add({x: 'a'});
```

It's pretty simple but it seems that Firebase does not like that object being passed into the add function.

I was able to get to the exact line where everything fails inside Google's Firestore `validate.js` file.

```
function extractBaseClassName(value) {
    let constructorName = 'Object';
    while (Object.getPrototypeOf(value) !== Object.prototype) {
        value = Object.getPrototypeOf(value); // <===== This returns null instead of an Object for some reason
        constructorName = value.constructor.name;
    }
    return constructorName;
}
```

**This is the exact error message stack:**

```
(node:90760) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'constructor' of null
    at extractBaseClassName (/Users/Moose/Development/crypto-accumulator/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/validate.js:35:33)
    at Object.customObjectMessage (/Users/Moose/Development/crypto-accumulator/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/validate.js:55:26)
    at Object.validateDocumentData (/Users/Moose/Development/crypto-accumulator/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/write-batch.js:608:36)
    at CollectionReference.add (/Users/Moose/Development/crypto-accumulator/functions/node_modules/@google-cloud/firestore/build/src/reference.js:1765:23)
    at runB (repl:43:6)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

***Update: A hunch...***

I believe the issue might be that `Object.getPrototypeOf(value) !== Object.prototype` is evaluating to `true` when it should be `false` since `{x: 'a'}` is an Object

Answer (score 1):

It seems the object is not a problem. I tried to reproduce it in my firestore and used following commands:

```
let  docId = 'test_document3'
async function f1() { 
    await db.collection('test_collection').doc(docId).collection('inside-collection').add({ x: 'c'}) 
}
f1()
```

Document have been added with no problem. You may try the same way.

Comment: Interesting so I moved the code into a firebase function and called it that way and it worked perfectly. Seems to be an issue with the firebase shell specifically. I might need to open a bug with them

Comment: If I understand correctly await can be called only inside async function, at least I don't know other way...